# Expand project tree view to currently open file

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm developing an Intellij Idea plugin and have a simple method that opens a file passed to it.

```
FileEditorManager editorManager = FileEditorManager.getInstance(project);
editorManager.openFile(myVirtualFile);
```

Everything works just fine, but I'd also like to have project view tree expanded to `myVirtualFile`.

I tried using an instance of `ProjectView` but couldn't find anything useful there. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't have knowledge in plugin development. But I think the behaviour that you want to achieve depends from the user settings `Autoscroll to source` and `Autoscroll from source` , which you can set when you click on the gear in the project view

Comment: Probably the code in this method does what you want: com.intellij.ide.projectView.impl.ProjectViewImpl.scrollFromSource()